# 3D Bounding Boxes without using neural networks

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, open3d

The problem is that:

1. I have input ".jpg" format pictures in one folder about 1200 pictures
2. Another folder containing ".txt" flies for labels for each pictures
   [class_index, BB_x, BB_y, BB_w, BB_h, BB3D_x1, BB3D_x2, BB3D_y1, BB3D_y2, BB3D_z1, BB3D_z2]. Below, you can find an example using these values in attachment. [Labels screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W2D5.png)
3. And camera matrix as below:

   cam_mtx = np.array([
   [358.5, 0.0,   512.0],
   [0.0,   358.5, 256.0],
   [0.0,   0.0,   1.0],
   ])

I need to develop a model to get 3d bounding boxes without using neural network techniques, any help, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont get it, if you already have BB3D_x1, BB3D_x2, BB3D_y1, BB3D_y2, BB3D_z1, BB3D_z2 (3d bounding box data), what do you want to compute now?

Comment: I need a model to train on those coordinated, and then it will predict the 3d bounding boxes for the other pictures

Comment: What is the camera matrix for? Are your images taken by the camera with said matrix? Is it the fundamental or essential matrix that you have, and have you calibrated the matrix to your particular camera?